# Graph visualization libraries for SWT/AWT

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt, graph-visualization

Is there a mature, solid open-source graph visualization library implementation for SWT or AWT (I am referring to sets of vertices connected with edges, not charts and diagrams)?

Which one do you use/recommend?

I saw [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) for SWT, but could not find a Maven repository for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend Prefuse:
http://prefuse.org/

Comment: Is there a corresponding Maven repo?

Comment: There's an ant repo at https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse . I don't know of a maven one though.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at JUNG ( http://jung.sourceforge.net/ )

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `Zest` (which I prefer), there is still `Draw2D`:

[Draw2D](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php)

Also, there is a good tutorial on this available here:

[Display a UML Diagram using Draw2D](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-Draw2d/GEF-Draw2d.html)

Finally, I found this Maven repository:

[Repository](http://unicore-dev.zam.kfa-juelich.de/maven/org/eclipse/draw2d/)

Don't really know much about Maven, but isn't this a repository for `Zest`?:

[Zest](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/org/eclipse/zest/)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Piccolo2D](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/), it supports 2D structured graphics and ZUI. [Here](http://www.piccolo2d.org/learn/grapheditor.html) is a simple demo of a graph builder. Also, [here](http://www.piccolo2d.org/applications/index.html#piccolo2d_java) are some Java applications that are based on Piccolo2D.

Answer (score 2):

For Zest Core:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.zest</groupId>
 <artifactId>core</artifactId>
```

For Zest Layout:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.zest</groupId>
<artifactId>layouts</artifactId>
```

For JUNG2

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
 <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```