# How to generate a line chart/graph for Error Rate & recognition rate in varying lighting conditions, varying database size and pose variation?

Tags: java, graph, comparison, linechart, face-recognition

I am working on a comparison paper for the first time which includes the comparison of EigenFaces, FisherFaces and LBPH algorithms using PCA & LDA. I am doing comparison on the basis of recognition in varying lighting conditions, varying database/TrainingImages size and pose variation. I need to find the recognition rate and error rate in all these conditions by plotting graphs between:

1. Error Rate and recognition rate in varying lighting conditions
2. Error Rate and recognition rate in varying database/TrainingImages size
3. Error Rate and recognition rate in pose variation

I don't know how can I plot line chart/Graph between them. I mean how can I get/measure values for these 3 conditions. I want to generate graphs on the run time not by feeding some predefined values. can anyone please suggest any method for this purpose?

Also please tell if graph generation is not possible by feeding values at run time. I am using JAVA AWT, jdk1.8.0_102 and Eclipse.

Comment: Please mention the Java GUI Toolkit you are using/planning to use. Is it Java FX or Java Swing or something else? Also, I think it should be possible to draw graphs from runtime data.

Comment: I am using JAVA AWT, jdk1.8.0_102 and Eclipse....I've edited my Question and added it there too..

Comment: Is it ok to use an external library? If yes, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546807/graph-visualization-libraries-for-swt-awt Also, in my opinion, AWT is an outdated technology and has lot of disadvantages, you should consider using Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: Actually I wanna know that how can I get/measure values for these 3 conditions so that i can plot graph.

Comment: Aren't these three conditions just variations to the training set and the input to the algorithm? What's your exact difficulty?

Comment: algorithms just do the recognition, they don't calculate light variation but if i input faces with bright light the recognition rate of these algorithms vary. some of them gives good recognition results but some do not.. My difficulty is how can I get values of recognition rate for graph generation, should i use supposed values or calculate, if calculate then how by reading pixel values or what??

Comment: If your work is about face-recognition, you should not take the difficulty of measuring these parameters. The database that you use should probably include these information for all images. Unfortunately, if it's not available, you have you do it yourself, but use some library like OpenCV to reduce your time.

Comment: Ok thank u, yes i am using OpenCV